# get json object attribute with 'dot' in name

Tags: json, object, attributes

*** Problem solved : json.stringify was the problem..  much easier to handle when its gone.

```js
var DBName = result['Document']['SW.Blocks.GlobalDB']['AttributeList']['Name'];
```

I have a xml file which describes a datablock from a PLC and want to get specific values with JS. 
I converted it with xml2js module, so i have a json object to work with.

```js
{
   "Document": {
      "Engineering": {
         "$": {
            "version": "V15"
         }
      },
      "SW.Blocks.GlobalDB": {
         "$": {
            "ID": "0"
         },             
        "HeaderAuthor": "",
        "HeaderFamily": "",
        "HeaderName": "",
        "HeaderVersion": "0.1",
        "Interface": {
 ... 
 ...
           "Name": "datentypen",
           "Number": "6",
           "ParameterModified": {
              "_": "2018-09-05T11:49:37.0862092Z",
              "$": {
                 "ReadOnly": "true"
              }
           },
        }
}
```

I want to print out the "Name" and the "Number", which are part of the "AttributeList".
So how to handle with the "SW.Blocks.GlobalDB"?

Getting error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'SW' of undefined"

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml = fs.readFileSync('datentypen.xml');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray: false});

parser.parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('xml2js.parse error: ',err);
    } else {
      var injson = JSON.stringify(result,null,3);
      console.log(injson);
//      var injson2 = JSON.parse(injson);
//      var DBnummer = injson.Document.SW.Blocks.GlobalDB.AttributeList["Name","Number"];
//      console.log(DBNummer);
    };
});
```

I read a lot about this theme but didnt found a concrete answer..
When i write ["SW.Blocks.GlobalDB"], an error about [ comes around.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reading the JSON array using Key-Value pair? I had similar issues but with a different programming language.

Comment: Hm that doesnt seems to work well..  for sure i did smth wrong, i got every single letter printed in a new line, that doesnt make any sense lol .. but thanks for the advice, i will go on trying